# Minimal bottleneck path in time-varying graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, approximation-algorithms

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$. The cost of each edge $e$ is a function of time, denoted by $w_e(t)$. Given a time interval $[0,T]$, for any path $P$ starting at $v_s$ at time $t\in[0,T]$, we denote $t_e^P$ the time an edge $e\in P$ is traversed. We ignore the time to pass $e=(u,v)$, i.e., at time $t_e^P$, we go from $u$ to $v$ with a cost $w_e(t)$. We may choose to wait for a certain time at any vertex. Let $w_P(t)=\sum_{e\in P} w_e(t_e^P)$ denote the cost of $P$ when starting from $v_s$ at time $t$. We seek a $v_s-v_t$ path $P$ to minimize $\max_{t\in[0,T]} w_P(t)$. How to approach this problem?

Comment: One way is to define Ricci flow on Graphs by the Olliver-Ricci curvature  and the Forman-Ricci curvature

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I am interested in algorithms solving the problem, instead of abstract math formulation.

Comment: Should the summand $c_e(t_e)$ instead be $w_e(t_e^P)$?

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you for pointing out. I have corrected the typo.

Comment: Also, $v_t$ is just the sink node and the subscript has nothing to do with time $t$?

Comment: $v_t$ is the sink.

Answer (score 1):

Call $P$ an $\varepsilon$-path if $\max_{t\in[0,T]}w_P(t)\leq\varepsilon$.
Define the duration of a path as the maximum $t_e^P$ over all edges $e$ on $P$.
For a vertex $u$, let $\tau_\varepsilon(u)$ be the infimum duration over all $\varepsilon$-path from $v_s$ to $u$.
Consider the problem of deciding whether an $\varepsilon$-path from $v_s$ to $v_t$ exists; that is, deciding whether $\tau_\varepsilon(v_t)\leq T$.
For any fixed $\varepsilon$, you can compute the values of $\tau_\varepsilon(u)$ for any vertex $u$ (and in particular $v_t$) using a modified version of Dijkstra's algorithm: use a priority queue that is initialized with the source vertex $v_s$ with priority $0$, using the invariant that enqueued vertices have a $\varepsilon$-path whose duration is their priority. When popping a vertex $u$  from the queue for the first time, say with priority $t$, set $\tau_\varepsilon(u):=t$, and enqueue all the neighbors $v$ with priority $t_{(u,v)}$, where $t_{(u,v)}$ is the first time $\geq\tau_\varepsilon(u)$ for which $w_{(u,v)}(t_{(u,v)})\leq\varepsilon$.

For the optimization version, observe that the optimum value of $\varepsilon$ can occur at the intersection of two functions $w_e$ and $w_{e'}$, or a local minimum of a single function $w_e$, or the value of a function $w_e$ at $t=0$ or $t=T$. So, taking into account the complexity of the functions $w_e$, there are only quadratically many candidate values for the optimum $\varepsilon$, which you can compute and binary search on using the decision problem.

Comment: Thank you. If we require that the path delay be upper-bounded by say $T'$ (basically we cannot wait too long), the optimization problem cannot be solved exactly. Am I correct?

Comment: I assume that by path delay, you mean the time between consecutive edges. If we are not allowed to revisit vertices, it is probably NP-hard to compute. If we are allowed to revisit vertices I'm not sure; you might still be able to solve it by storing the time-intervals for which you can enter a vertex, instead of the earliest time you can enter a vertex.

Comment: Agree, but why revisiting vertices? I can wait there instead of revisiting the same vertex.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you mean by the path delay.

Comment: By path delay I mean that traversing each edge $e$ incurs a delay $d_e$. We impose another constraint such that when starting at time $t$, we need to arrive at $v_t$ by time $t+D$ with $D$ being a tolerable delay.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want for consecutive edges $e$ and $e'$ that $t_{e'}^P-t_e^P\geq d_e$. That's still solvable, for the decision problem you change $\tau_{\varepsilon}(u):=t+d_e$. For the optimization problem, instead of intersections between $w_e$ and $w_{e'}$ you need to consider the values $\varepsilon=w_e(t)=w_{e'}(t+d)$ where $d$ is the delay between traversing $e$ and $e'$. If all $d_e$ are small integers, there are only polynomially many values of $d$ to consider. Otherwise, binary searching on $\varepsilon$ gives an approximation that is arbitrarily close to the optimum.

Comment: I did not see why there are only polynomially many values of d? We may wait some time before traversing an edge.

Comment: Consider the minimum value of $\varepsilon$ for which a path exists, and assume that it is minimal due to the 'delay'. Then, assuming all functions $w_e$ are continuous, the bottleneck is caused by two edges $e$ and $e'$ (not necessarily consecutive) that have function value $\varepsilon$ at times $t$ and $t'$ respectively, where $d:=t'-t$ is the time between entering $e$ and $e'$. As the bottleneck is caused by delay, we do not pause on the subpath from $e$ to $e'$, so $d$ is a sum of  $O(n)$ edge delays. If all $d_e$ are integers $\leq k$, there are $O(kn)$ possible values for $d$.

Comment: why there are two bottleneck edges?

Comment: Think of them as the start and end of a path of vertices that you cannot afford to pause at.

Comment: I can see that if there are two bottlenecks, the part between them is "tight", but if there is only one bottleneck?

Comment: The tight path is the bottleneck, and always lies between two edges. If the optimum is determined by a single edge, the delay is not relevant, and the optimum value is based on a local minimum, or a boundary condition (related to t=0 or t=T) instead.

Comment: I see what you mean. If $w_e(t)$ and $w'_{e'}(t)$ overlap for certain range, the number of intersections may be infinite. How to deal this case?

Comment: It's sufficient to consider the endpoints of the range of overlap (only proper intersections give candidate values of $\varepsilon$).

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I still have another concern on the Dijkstra-based algorithm, given that my problem also has a time dimension. Suppose that we are currently processing $v$ and its neighbor $u$, further suppose there are two paths $P_1$ and $P_2$ from $s$ to $v$ and $P_2$ is dominated by $P_1$, so only $P_1$ is recorded in the Dijkstra-based algorithm. However, it is possible that the path $P_2+(v,u)$ is better than $P_1+(v,u)$ due to the time dimension (we seek to minimize $\max_{t\in[0,T]} w_P(t)$, which differs from Dijkstra). Am I missing sth?

Comment: I misread the question. Dijkstra minimizes the bottleneck edge, not the sum of edge weights. To minimize the sum, maintain functions $\gamma_v(t)$ representing the cheapest way to reach vertex $v$ before time $t$. We have $\gamma_s(t)=0$ for all $t\geq 0$, and for each edge $uv$ and $t'+d_{uv}\leq t$, you have $\gamma_v(t')\leq\gamma_u(t')+w_{uv}(t)$. Naively you can initialize all functions $\gamma_u(t):=\infty$, and update $\gamma_v(t):=\min(\gamma_v(t),\min_{t'\leq t-d_{uv}}\gamma_u(t')+w_{uv}(t'))$ for all edges, until reaching a fixed point (i.e. after updating each edge linearly often).

Comment: I did not quite catch it. Let me pose the question in another formulation. Each edge $e$  is on for certain time intervals and off otherwise. Traversing $e$ incurs a delay $d_e$ and is possible only it is on. Given $v_s$ and $v_t$ and a time horizon from $0$ to $T$, we seek a path such that at any time $t$ you depart from $v_s$, you can arrive at $v_t$ by time $t+D$. Or in another formulation, for each path $P$ we can define some sort of worst-case delay as the longest delay required to arrive at $v_t$ from $v_s$ for any departure time $t\in[0,T]$. We seek a path with minimal worst-case delay.

Comment: Given the limit on the number of characters, I have to make the formulation short. Hope you can understand it. Could you pls put your Dijkstra-based algo in this context? Thank you. The key point is whether we can grow properly a path.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(i,t,W)$ be the minimum cost of a path to the sink, starting from node $i$ at time $t$ with current maximum $W$.  We want to compute $f(v_s,0,-\infty)$, and $f$ satisfies the recursion:
$$
f(i,t,W)=
\begin{cases}
W &\text{if $i=v_t$} \\
\min\limits_{e=(i,j)\in E,\ t'\in [t,T]} f(j,t',\max(W,w_e(t')) &\text{if $i\not=v_t$}
\end{cases}
$$
As an approximation, you can discretize the time interval to a finite set for each $e\in E$, as well as the set of $W$ values.